# nginx: parse *.cgi as php

Tags: parsing, nginx, config

Is it possible to parse *.cgi files as php, and how?

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
      fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/htdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

This is for my .php files. Just rename to *.cgi dosn't work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the first line to be location `~ \.cgi$`? That would be my first guess